# sin(x) TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
in[]:x=linspace(0,2*pi,50)

in[]:plot(x,sin(x))

Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "<ipython-input-55-3271d4c7a0b1>", line 1, in <module>
    plot(x,tan(x))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Comment: How is `sin` defined? Is this `np.sin` ?

Comment: Your error message has `plot(x,tan(x))` but your code has `plot(x,sin(x))`. Which is it?

Comment: It is plot(x,sin(x))

Answer (score 0):

Using the numpy library this should work.
`import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x))`